# Loopback middleware - how to customized error response

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

I have API's to provides features for e-commerce application.
I want to customized the error response the json structure.

Can anyone help me with this???

Answer (score 1):

Use [Strong error handler](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Using+strong-error-handler). Just make sure you remove any error handling middlewares you currently have and place this one at the end of all your routes.

Comment: This doesn't change the JSON structure. It just helps us to change the log message.